Svelte 5 Runes - unable to bind child component props directly to parent component props
In Svelte 5, using Runes syntax, I'm trying to bind a prop from a child component to the prop of a parent component directly.
The only way I am able to get this to work is by creating a local state variable in the parent and updating the local state value first, before updating the prop with the local state value.
I did not have to do this in Svelte 4 and this seems unnecessarily wordy and clunky.
What am I missing?
Example working binding:
<script>
   let { someProp = $bindable() } = $props();

   let localPropState = $state(someProp);

   $effect(() => {
       someProp = localPropState;
   });
</script>

<ChildComponent bind:localPropState />

Example not working binding:
<script>
   let { someProp = $bindable() } = $props();
</script>

<ChildComponent bind:someProp />


Show the ChildComponent definition and how this component is being used. As long as the properties are defined/used correctly and the input is a $state, this will work without any extra effect.

Thanks, I fixed the issue. The issue was that further up the component tree someProp was still being set as a writable instead of Svelte 5's $state

The problem was that further up the component tree someProp was still being set as Svelte 4 $writable instead of Svelte 5 $state.
